# How to list the Elastic IP (EIP) addresses via CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How to get all the  Elastic IP (EIP) addresses present in a subnet via CDK ?

My purpose is to whitelist those elastic ips in another account through the CDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find a construct with the logical name of EIP in the public subnets of your VPC. Afterwards you should be able to sue Ref to export the EIP address:

```
    const eips = vpc.publicSubnets.map(subnet => (subnet as PublicSubnet).node.findChild('EIP') as CfnEIP);

    this.exportValue(Fn.join(",", eips.map(n => n.ref)), {
        name: "elastic-ips"
    })

    // or one by one

    new CfnOutput(this, 'EIP1', {
        value: eips[0].ref
    })
    new CfnOutput(this, 'EIP2', {
        value: eips[1].ref
    })
```

Comment: `findChild('EIP')` on my public subnet is returning empty response. i could however see that public subnet is associated with NAT gateway and NAT gateway has elastic ip addresses

Comment: What's the exact aws-cdk version you're using?

Comment: It is cdk version 1

Answer (score 0):

I am using CDKv2 and even though `PublicSubnet` has as Child with `id = EIP`, `.findChild` doesn't return anything and cause errors in stack synthesis.

Here is my version.

```js
    const eips = vpc.publicSubnets
      .map((subnet) =>
        (subnet as PublicSubnet).node.children
          .filter((child) => child.node.id == 'EIP')
          .map((child) => child as CfnEIP),
      )
      .flat();

    for (let eip of eips) {
      // Release EIPs on stack removal
      eip.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
    }
```